# In what ways do Japanese children overgeneralize conjugation patterns?

Tags: conjugations, child-speech

(Preface: I'm not well-versed in language acquisition, so the context I've provided here will be dumbed-down, or perhaps just dumb.)

**Context:** When children acquire their first language, they typically go through a phase where they take grammatical rules (e.g. "form past tense by adding -ed to a verb") and apply them in situations where they aren't applicable (e.g. using **goed* as the past tense of *go*). This is called **overgeneralization**. Children acquiring English as a first language overgeneralize verb conjugations all over the place - "I ated the candy", "She telled me to do it", etc.

Since Japanese has fewer irregular conjugations than English, I expect overgeneralization (in the context of conjugation) to be less visible, but I doubt that it is absent altogether. I have, for example, heard **iikunai* as the overgeneralized negative of *ii* "good" in place of *yokunai*. (Albeit this was a child character in an anime, not a real child, so this may not be representative.)

**Question:** Do children make similar errors with irregular verbs and other conjugatable words? For example, might they use **shiru* as the 終止形 of *suru* "to do" or **kinai* as the negative of *kuru* "to come"? What about with irregular honorifics like *irassharu*, *gozaru*? (I guess children wouldn't use these as much, since keigo is mastered relatively late...)

I would also be interested in cases where children incorrectly treat non-conjugatable words as conjugatable, e.g. (to use some examples from the comments), **ippakunai* as the negative of *ippai* "a lot; much" or **kireikunai* as the negative of *kirei* "pretty".

Comment: I usually ignore all the papers about child acquisition, but IIRC a lot of overgeneralizations in child Japanese have to do with particles, that is, overgeneralizing syntax rather than morphology.  I think I've seen mention of overgeneralizing に and の.

Comment: いっぱくない。にはくある。^_^

Comment: 私は小さい時、「きれいじゃない」を「きれいくない」とか、「飲めない」を「飲められない」(「食べる>>食べられない」だから、「飲む>>飲められない」と思った)、「かっこよくない」を「かっこいくない」(「かっこいい」が一つの形容詞だと思った)、「できる」を「できられない」(なぜかはわからない)とか言ってた記憶があります。

Comment: @Choko -- interesting. My wife as a learner sometimes still says きれいくない, perhaps suggesting that at least some of these overgeneralization patterns extend beyond just child learners. I'd be interested in studies comparing child vs adult learners and such patterns.

Comment: @Choko, my mother (a native) uses きれくない. I think maybe it's a dialectal thing.

Comment: @dainichi, I'm curious -- does she use any other similar conjugations, like きれかった or きれく[verb]?

Comment: 「きれくない・きれいくない・きれかった」「飲めれない」「違くて」などは大人で使っている人もいますが、基本的には「[乱れた日本語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B9%B1%E3%82%8C)」の類いだと思います。

Comment: @dainichi "uses" >> Do you mean... she still uses it? Maaybe as a 若者言葉?

Comment: @Choko, yes, she still uses it. She's in her 60's so she's definitely not a 若者, but she left Japan when she was in her 30's, maybe it was a 若者言葉 back then.

Comment: @Choko, actually, it might be more きれかった than きれくない. Googling, I definitely see pages suggesting that it's 関西弁 or 大阪弁, e.g. http://nanapi.jp/51230/

Comment: Just now I heard a Japanese boy around 2 years old say 「電話してとく」 instead of 「電話しとく」 (although 電話しとく itself is 若者言葉)

Comment: 「～～しておく」が「～～しとく」になるのって若者言葉ですか。口語で年齢関係なく使われる縮約(「え」の脱落)だと思うんですけど。

Comment: 幼児の言葉の間違いって、住んでいる地域もだけど、まず親(or身近な大人)の出身地や方言によっても違ってくるでしょうし、あと、同じような環境でも、子ども一人一人によってすごく違ってくるので(個性・個体差がある)、一概に「こうだ。」とは言えないと思います。

Comment: @Choko ごめんなさい、大人も普通に使ってると思います(^^;)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways that these over-generalizations occur doing child language acquisition. They do in fact occur -- often -- in Japanese. In fact, I think it is safe to say that they occur in every language.

There's a rather in depth list of examples of some of these over-generalizations available in the papers referenced below. I will describe one example here: the over-generalization of ～らせて (e.g. as seen in 遅【おく】らせて) and ～させて (e.g. 食べさせて). Thus many children will say things like:

> おきらせて and おきさせて (＝おこして).

Even earlier than that, Japanese children will often simply use 自動詞 to express the meaning of a 他動詞, as seen in:

> かあさん、でんしゃ、うごいてくれ。(＝かあさん、でんしゃを**うごかして**くれ)

There are many more papers and likely books written on this subject, but any Japanese-language introductory book on language acquisition should have a bunch more examples.

---

#### References

- [荒井文雄(2003)日本語における起因他動詞の習得段階－起因他動詞をめぐる誤用のもつ意味－『京都産業大学論集』、人文科学系列第30号、pp.1-38](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~arai/acquisition%20causative.html)
- [荒井文雄(2006)日本語における可能表現の習得過程『京都産業大学論集』、人文科学系列第34号、pp.1-23](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~arai/acquisition%20potential.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not really overgeneralization, but when I was in Tokyo I've heard quite a few little kids use 連用形＋して instead of 連用形＋音便＋て to form て-form (i.e. 飲みして, 待ちして), likely to avoid the messy 音便 rules. I guess this is some sort of new form that spread among kids.

Edit: After recalling a bit, it seems that this "error" comes up the most often with 〜てみる. So kids would say ちょっと待って, but 飲みしてみて.

Comment: Never heard kids in Tokyo (or anywhere) say 飲みして or 待ちして.

Comment: Did you maybe hear 飲まして ("let me drink") instead? I've never heard 飲みして either.

Comment: TBH it was a few tiny kids running around in a group in 未来館 with grammar that is very peculiar in other parts (I swear some of them generalize 〜い to 〜かる for adjectives!), so maybe it is some weird constructed dialect these particular kids use for fun. Probably they'll end up growing up into conlangers like JRR Tolkien :P

Answer (score 0):

The kinds of mistakes that children make depend on how often they hear the correct speech around them. From my experience, Japanese children make fewer mistakes in conjugating verbs than in using particles properly.
I've heard adult women use "kireiku nai" deliberately for the same of emphasizing their point. My first Japanese teacher used to say that you spend your first year of Japanese study learning all of the rules, and then the rest of your life learning when to break them. I've also heard adults say yon-nichi instead of yoka to differentiate between four days and eight days.

Answer (score 0):

I expect children in all cultures go through a trial and error period of well intended but amusing errors as their ability to speak develops.

This paper looks at the development of Japanese children's narrative abilities, comparing the narrative given for a series of pictures by several age groups up to adult.

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/245402146_Anchor_tense_in_Japanese_Narrative
(Short version:http://csjarchive.cogsci.rpi.edu/proceedings/2006/iccs/p119.pdf)

It does not identify errors so much as track how a child's ability to relate a story changes as he/she gets older. Basically as a child begins to appreciate aspect and tense he/she starts to set all narratives in the past (たーform).  Then, as this sense develops, the child starts  to introduce expressions in the るーpresent tense aswell.